# How to get value from database?

Tags: php, database

I have table person.

```
id, age
--  -----
1   2
2   5
3   6
4   7
5   8
```

I want to get one value from age. the result of my code bellow is 25678. How can I get just one value.

```
$query= "SELECT age FROM person";
$result= mysql_query($query) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
     $age= $row['age'];  
     echo $age; // the result will be 25678
     // i want to get a value from the result ex = 5 or 6
     //I try with call the index like my code bellow but It's not working
         echo $age[1]; 
         echo $age[2]; 
    }
```

can somebody help me...

Comment: Presumably `2,5,6,7,8` is a string and not an array. Use `explode()` to split the numbers into an array that you can use as `$age[1]` etc.

Comment: To be precise, `mysql` is outdated. Soon php won't be supporting `mysql` so better start using `mysqli`.

Comment: Are you storing 2,5,6,7,8 in a single row?

Comment: It is not in a single row. So when Id = 1, age = 2. Id = 2, age = 5, id = 3, age = 6 etc

Comment: @nickhar: I think `explode()` not required..

Comment: I don't see any problem in your query. Are you sure you table has data?

Comment: Yes, if I call $age, the result is 25678. But I cannot call just one of the value with $age[1].

Comment: @VictoriaCho: Sorry couldn't get your question are you asking you want only a single age ex: 5?

Comment: Ya, I want only a single age.

Comment: See my updated answer for your requirement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Well, if you want one of the ages. Save all rows in an array and fetch the index of your choice.**

Example:

```
 $query= "SELECT age FROM person";
    $result= mysql_query($query) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());
    $ageArray;
    $i=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
         //$age= $row['age'];  
         $ageArray[$i++]=$row['age'];
        }
    echo $ageArray[1];
```

I hope this is what you want...

Comment: No, I mean I want to get one value of the result 25678. So, I use $age[1] to get 5. But its not working.

Comment: @VictoriaCho that doesn't work friend....which value do you want exactly? What properties should it have? Update your question accordingly...

Comment: @VictoriaCho see the second edit...I have updated code according to your requirements........

Comment: This solve my prob after you add $ageArray[$i++] on your code.. Thank you so much this solve my prob :)

Comment: and I wanna vote up your answer but I can't cz I don't have anough reputation here. Sorry, friend :'(

Comment: there is an upvote and downvote option on left right, they are for voting....and check the tick mark below the down arrow to accept my answer....you can upvote after you get enough rep

Comment: I asked you to upvote my answer that's it.... there is an up-arrow beside my answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $age = $row[0];
  echo $age."<br />";
}
```

While loop will run until the end of $result array. In each loop, it will echo current row.

Comment: add "<br />" after each echo

Comment: You are calling one value but in html, without <br />, content goes inline

Comment: that means that you don't have more than 1 age in some record.

explode(",","2,5,6,7,8") will give the following array:

array(2,5,6,7,8);

Comment: Do you even have commas in your record?

Comment: oh sorry, myb my question is ambiguous. I mean 2,5,6,7,8 is not in a single row. So when Id = 1, age = 2. Id = 2, age = 5, id = 3, age = 6 etc

Comment: Then use the first code in my answer. I added <br /> for you.

Comment: This solution is no different than the question. You have just added a `<br/>` tag.

Comment: @Dibya I have edited my answer which had 3 solutions for 3 different problems because question was unclear. Since it is clear now, solution is working.

Comment: the result $age from your code is 2,5,6,7,8, rite? so how can I get one value of the result? if I need 8. I can't use $age[4] to call it.

Comment: @VictoriaCho Your original code is good. You are getting 25678 because you are not echoing <br /> so content is displayed in one line...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query= "SELECT age FROM person";
$result= mysql_query($query) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());
$array_r;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       array_push($array_r,$row['age']);
    }

echo '<pre/>';
print_r($array_r);
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought two things in your case:

**1. By Passing condition to query:**
As you want to get only one value then you should have to pass a condition based on `id` field so that you will get only single value

```
$query= "SELECT age FROM person where id={$id}"; //here $id may be any numeric value which you have specified
$result= mysql_query($query) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());
$age = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if(count($age)){
    echo $age[0]['age']; //this will print only single value based on condition you have specified in SQL query
}
```

**2. By assigning result (age) to an array and then print**

```
$query= "SELECT age FROM person";
$result= mysql_query($query) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());
$age = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $age[] = $row['age'];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($age);

echo $age[1]; //this will print 5
echo $age[2]; //this will print 6
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query= "SELECT age FROM person";
$result= mysql_query($query) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());
//take age in an array
$age=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

     array_push($age, $row['age']);
     echo $row['age'];  // the result will be 25678

     // i want to get a value from the result ex = 5 or 6
     //I try with call the index like my code bellow but It's not working
         echo $age[1]; 
         echo $age[2]; // now u will get desired result by calling index of $age array
    }
```